# how can I create a derby databse table using Apache ant scripts.

Tags: ant, derby

I did build derby using apache ant. So how can I create database tables which can be run using ant.

Comment: could you please clarify a bit? What did you do with ant right now and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

ANT's standard SQL task allows you to create tables as normal:

```
<target name="create-table">
        <sql print="true" failOnConnectionError="true"
              driver="${db.driver}"
              url="${db.url}"
              userid="${db.user}"
              password="${db.pass}">
              CREATE TABLE customer
                 (First_Name char(50),
                 Last_Name char(50),
                 Address char(50),
                 City char(50),
                 Country char(25),
                 Birth_Date datetime);              
        </sql>
</target>
```

Personally, I use liquibase to manage my database schemas:

- http://www.liquibase.org/manual/ant